# SQL: Why am I getting an error with reference to my end in my while loop?

Tags: sql, while-loop

I have tables for several years that I need to put together. I try to solve this with a WHILE loop according to the code belove:

```
declare @t int = 10

while @t <= 11

  --Erase tables if they exist.
    if object_id(['a\b].rot@t', 'U') is null
    drop table [a\b].rot@t
    if object_id(['a\c].rot@t', 'U') is null
    drop table [a\c].rot@t

  --Create tables.
    select *
    into rot@t
    from rot_ftg_@t

    insert into rot@t
    select *
    from rot_ens_@t

  --Update macrovar.
    set @t = @t + 1

end
```

When I run this script I get the following error messages:
"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near 'end'."

I use msn sql server and it appears to be version 14.0.

The short loop intervall is just for test and I'm sorry that I can't provide any example data due to company rules.

I would appreciate any help I can get, thanks in advance!

Regards
MarJer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing your begin statement (assuming rest of your code is fine, that should fix your error for the begin/end issue.

```
while @t <= 11
   BEGIN

  --Erase tables if they exist.
    if object_id(['a\b].rot@t', 'U') is null
    drop table [a\b].rot@t
    if object_id(['a\c].rot@t', 'U') is null
    drop table [a\c].rot@t

  --Create tables.
    select *
    into rot@t
    from rot_ftg_@t

    insert into rot@t
    select *
    from rot_ens_@t

  --Update macrovar.
    set @t = @t + 1

END
```